# CSS page width issue

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to eliminate the horizontal scroll bar on our Intranet. There is nothing but background to the right of the page and I have been struggling with this for several hours now. We have CSS and HTML for the homepage, but use JavaScript to navigate multiple pages. All of the pages pull their settings from the CSS and all of the pages have this issue leading me to believe it is with the CSS. Below is my CSS, please let me know if and where I may need to make changes.

```css
html, body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFEBD6;
    color: #665E56;
}
header {
    text-align:center;
    width: 600px;
}
nav {
    line-height:20px;
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    height: 40%;
}
section {
    position: Absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color:#fff3e5;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #665E56;
    min-height:350px;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:7px;
}
table {
    text-align:center;
    border:1;
}
th, td {
    padding:10px;
}
.indent80 {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.indented {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.indent40 {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width:500px;    
}

/*.push-footer, .push { */
/*    height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */    
/*} */
#quicklinks {
    padding-left:5px;
    position: absolute;
    left:181px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border:3px raised;
    padding:10px;
    width:90%;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: html, body { position: absolute; } ??? - really?

Comment: you need to post your HTML code, CSS alone won't be of any use

Comment: simple question: isn't that you, for mistake, zoomed into your page? when you zoom in, it appears the horizontal scroll

Comment: Johannes: That actually was Relative before I posted. I was literally tweaking everything I could think of to change this. 

Orange Orange: I am not zoomed in and am at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, body section add `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.... I hate Web Browsers sometimes.... When I would make a change I would refresh the page, but apparently I also needed to clear the Cache.

I cleared the Cache by holding Control, Right Clicking on the Refresh button and selecting "Empty Cache and Hard Reload." Link below.

https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.Wi64fmiPKUl

Thank you all for your help!